# lsnrctl is not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, ubuntu, listener

I have managed to install `Oracle 11g` on `Ubuntu 14.04` through lots of pain. I managed to install it in the end but `listener` does not seem to be working and even responding any command.

My `/home/oracle/.bash_profile` is

```
R=$TMP; export TMPDIR

ORACLE_HOSTNAME=belgenet-test.localdomain; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
DB_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/db_1; export DB_HOME
ORACLE_HOME=$DB_HOME; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=orcl; export ORACLE_SID
ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER=$ORACLE_HOME export ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER
ORACLE_TERM=xterm; export ORACLE_TERM
BASE_PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export BASE_PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch:$BASE_PATH; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/JRE:$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
```

My `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.0.1.23      belgenet-test

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My `ORACLE_HOME` and `PATH` variables are working:

```
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ echo $PATH
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/OPatch:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/OPatch:/usr/sbin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/OPatch:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

However, `lsnrctl` commands does not respond at all:

```
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ lsnrctl status
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ lsnrctl start
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$
```

What might be the problem?

PS: I can connect to `sqlplus`

Edit 1:

My `listener.ora` file contents:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u02/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = belgenet-test)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

Edit 2:

My `tnsnames.ora` file:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.1.23)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

`tnsping orcl` result:

```
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 03-DEC-2015 17:12:15

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.1.23)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

`lsnrctl status` does not give any output **at all**

Edit 3:

`lsnrctl` permissions:

```
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ ls -lah lsnrctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 0 Aug 24  2013 lsnrctl
```

If I run `chmod 755 lsnrctl`, then `lsnrctl` does not work at all with the error message `-sh: lsnrctl: command not found` but `chmod +x` makes `listener` runnable (with still no output).

The owner of `lsnrctl` is `oracle:oinstall`

Edit 4:

Ownership of `lsnrctl`

```
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ chmod 755 lsnrctl
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ lsnrctl start
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ chmod +x lsnrctl
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ lsnrctl start
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$ ls -lh lsnrctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 0 Aug 24  2013 lsnrctl
oracle@belgenet-test:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin$
```

Edit 5:

OK, I got the problem. `ls` command displayed that the size of `lsnrctl` file was 0 bytes. I copied `lsnrctl` from another computer and now it gives an output (still an error though):

```
oracle@belgenet-test:~$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 04-DEC-2015 09:27:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00517: Lost contact
   Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45590/discussion-on-question-by-iso-9001-lsnrctl-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 1):

Your lsnrctl has 0 bytes so either you didn't install Oracle software correctly or your installation is damaged. So reinstall Oracle software.

Comment: It had 0 bytes before but I copied it from another server. It is giving connection error. I believe it is best to re-install Oracle. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a line (`ADDRESS_LIST`) missing in your `listener.ora` file:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = BELGENETTEST)(PORT = 1521))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      )
    )
  )
```

The command `lsnrctl status` should give an output with its parameters and a list of databases that run on this server.

Check the `network\admin` directory on the client machine to check if you have a `tnsnames.ora` file that has the information to connect to the database. Check it with the command `tnsping orcl`.